# C++ generic type instantiation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense

I am new to C++. I have the following C++ code:

```
template <typename T, int length>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(T values[length])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            list[i] = values[i];
        }
        friend bool operator<(const Vector<T, length>& left,
            const Vector<T, length>& right)
        {
            bool result = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            result &= left.list[i] < right.list[i];
            return result;
        }
    private:
    T list[length];
    };


    int main()
    {
        int first[] = {1, 2}, second[] = {2, 3}; 
        Vector<int, 2> vector1(first), vector2(second);
        cout << (vector1 < vector2) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I tried to compile it under VC++ express 2010. It returns the following error messages for the following two line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
result &= left.list[i] < right.list[i];
```

When I put the cursor on "length", it reports identifier "length" is undefined

When I put the cursor on "left", it returns expression must have arithmetic, enum, or pointer type

When I put the cursor on "list", it returns member "Vector::list is inaccessible.

Could anyone give some help and tell me how to correct the code? Thanks a lot.

Edit: Thanks a lot. I have fixed the issue. It seems VS 2010 does not work. I upgrade to 2013 version. Now it is working fine. Here I have another question regarding the implementation of the generic type. I have the following class:

```
class Int
{
public:
    Int(int i = 0) {this->i = i;}
private:
    int i;
};
```

I tried to implement this class in the main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    Int first[] = {Int(1), Int(2)}, second[] = {Int(2), Int(3)}; 
    Vector<Int, 2> vector1(first), vector2(second);
    cout << (vector1 < vector2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It still does not compile. I guess there is something wrong in the class Int. Could anyone give some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Friend functions don't inherit template parameters.

Comment: @chris Not true. This compiles fine with a recent clang++ and g++. You do have access to names of the class scope when defining a friend function inside the class definition.

Comment: *"When I put the cursor on"* So those are intellisense errors? What is the output of the compiler when you try to compile it?

Comment: `Vector(T values[length])` might not do what you expect it to do. It is equivalent to `Vector(T* values)`.

Comment: @dyp, Well TIL then :)

Comment: Compiles on VS2013 as well. And to add to what dyp said about the constructor argument, you may want to change it to `Vector(T const (&values)[length])` to only accept an array of a specific length.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be a compiler issue.

Your code seems to compile OK with a more recent compiler such as GCC-4.8.1, using something like

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

A GCC compiler for Windows can be downloaded from http://mingw.org/, and comes with most Linux distributions. I haven't tried VS2013. In general, MinGW and clang has better c++ standards support.

Comment: The OP isn't using variadic templates anywhere, and from the description it's not even clear whether these are only Intellisense errors or compiler errors.

Comment: You are right about variadics. What's this int template called then? Apparently, VS2010 doesn't support this template feature well here and that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: It's a non-type template parameter, and I highly doubt VS2010 doesn't support it.

Comment: @Praetorian OK, I've corrected my answer. Still, it's only my guess that this is a compiler issue with VS2010. I haven't seem VS complain about any errors when it compiles